# Way to detect if there is a black curve or straight line in python

Tags: python, opencv, detection

I'm woking on finding curve or straight line in Biomedical images. My task is to remove images that have black line with curve or straight like below example.

[image: Image of black curve line]

On the Biomedical image I try to process, noises except cells don't need on my analysis.

As we know, it may be helped using this method.

```
cv2.HoughLinesP()
```

But HoughLinesP() alogrithm is just effective in detecting "Straight" lines. I already tested and checked this result.

As seen in my image uploaded, that shape is neither 100% curve nor 100% straight. So I think I may approach on "Sequence" concept.  Those shapes are all LINES, so it means all pixels are connected as a series of pixel.

So about this issue, I hope someone gives me ideas or hints.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you tried ridge detection ? https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/auto_examples/edges/plot_ridge_filter.html

Comment: your explanation didn't help me understand the problem. please post some pictures to *show* the situation.

Comment: Perhaps threshold, then thin to get the medial axis (center line). Then measure curvature at each point on the center line. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvature

Comment: @endive1783 Great way! I tried. But I want to detect only black line not cell area. So in images with cell aren't that much useful. Thank you for good idea!